# About Dictionaries in C# or any other language?

Tags: c#, python, dictionary

I am just going through with this problem and thought of taking suggestions from you guys. I am new to C# if any of you can help I will really appreciate that. And it's not a homework problem just going through with self study material.

**Input**: two integer parameters between 1 and 50

**Output**: a Dictionary ; whose keys are all the integers between the two input parameters, inclusive, and whose values are the number of occurrences of the letter ‘e’ contained in the English spelling of the corresponding key.

For example, if I call CreateECountDictionary(6, 11), I expect to get a dictionary with the following (key,
    value) pairs:

```
(6, 0) (“six” has no ‘e’s)
(7, 2) (“seven” has two ‘e’s)
(8, 1) (“eight” has one ‘e’)
(9, 1) (“nine” has one ‘e’)
(10, 1) (“ten” has one ‘e’)
(11, 3) (“eleven” has three ‘e’)
```

Any suggestions to start with algorithms and coding in any language (C# preferred)?

Comment: Algorithms are typically not tied to a specific language.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1164635/Converting-Numbers-to-Text-in-Csharp  should get you started....

Answer (score 2):

You should split the problem into separate pieces.

1. A method to count the number of a specific character in a string (hint: you can use the linq Count() method).
2. A method to write an integer as an English text representation.
3. A loop to go over the numbers and create the text representations, count the 'e's and put them into a dictionary.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Some basic (incomplete) code for #2 (as requested in comments).

```
 private static readonly string[] numbers = new string[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

 private static string GetEnglishStringFromNumber(int number)
 {
     if (number >= 0 && number < 9)
     {
         return numbers[number];
     }
     //TODO - do teens and more complex numbers.
     //TODO - negative numbers.
     throw new NotImplementedException("TODO");
 }
```

Comment: That would make a great comment but I would hardly consider it as an answer to the question. I will not downvote it but I think you should at least consider to convert it to a comment, or add some code to it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I wanted to answer about method, because the OP is looking for algorithms, and wants to learn how to do the code themselves. Publishing the solution would be my usual go-to, but it would seem to spoil the OP's learning experience.

Comment: I can relate to that. I didn't suggest to write all the code for this, but a simple example would make a difference - for instance, instead of just writing "A method to write an integer as en English text..." actually write something that would perform at least a part of this task (say, 0 through 9).

Comment: @ZoharPeled I've put in some basic code as per your suggestion.